# Ubuntu 20.04 -- Where do I find options for desktop background images?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-background

Changing the desktop background image in Ubuntu 20.04 is easy.  Just open settings (gear in upper right corner of screen), choose background and click the image you want.  You can add your own image by right-clicking the image or image file and choosing "Set as wallpaper".  I've done that, but I don't get the entire image.  Portions are cropped from the top and the left edge.  Where do I find the image options?  It would be nice to center the image, or maybe stretch it.  Seems like there used to be a "fill" option.  Where are those options?  They aren't in settings and Gnome Tweaks doesn't have them either.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Tweaks -> Appearance and below the Background section there is an Adjustment Dropbar. Pick the one that suits you and I think that will help.

[image: Shown in Image Here]

Comment: That worked great!  Wish I'd seen that dropdown before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

without gnome-tweak and as a general approach, how to search for the proper place and discover available options? `gsettings` has some helpful commands. For your particular case:

```
$ gsettings list-schemas | grep background
org.gnome.desktop.background
...    
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background 
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
...
$ gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options
enum
'none'
'wallpaper'
'centered'
'scaled'
'stretched'
'zoom'
'spanned'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'wallpaper'
```